# Anti-Phishing software with batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a basic anti-phishing software with batch. I am using it to delete html files that are similar to the gmail login page. Here's my code:

```
@echo off
color fc
title Anti-Phishing
cls
echo ===============
echo [Anti-Phishing]
echo ===============
echo If There's no message ,You are protected.
set /p a=Enter a HTML file to scan: 
for /f %%x in ('findstr /i /m "gmail google add account" %a%.html') do (
    if /i %%x equ %a%.html (
        for /f %%z in ('findstr /i /b /m "tskill del copy shutdown ipconfig ren reg" %a%.html') do (
            if /i %%z equ %a%.html (
                cls
                echo Fake Page Detected!!
                del %a%.html
                echo %a%.html was deleted....
                pause >nul
            )
        )
    )
)
pause >nul
```

It says that it cannot open the html file. Please help me understand my mistake. I am pretty new to batch.

Comment: What is your html filename?  Add a line like `echo "%a%" "%%x"&pause` and see what is on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code a little bit improved:

```
@echo off
color fc
title Anti-Phishing
cls
echo ===============
echo [Anti-Phishing]
echo ===============
echo If There's no message ,You are protected.
set "HtmlFile=""
set /p "HtmlFile=Enter a HTML file to scan: "
set "HtmlFile=%HtmlFile:"=%"
if "%HtmlFile%"=="" goto :EOF
if "%HtmlFile:~-5%"==".html" set "HtmlFile=%HtmlFile:~0,-5%"
if "%HtmlFile%"=="" goto :EOF
if not exist "%HtmlFile%.html" (
    echo File "%HtmlFile%.html" not found.
    echo.
    echo Exit with any key ...
    pause>nul
    goto :EOF
)
for /f %%x in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /m "gmail google add account" "%HtmlFile%.html"') do (
    if /i %%x equ "%HtmlFile%.html" (
        for /f %%z in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /b /m "tskill del copy shutdown ipconfig ren reg" "%HtmlFile%.html"') do (
            if /i "%%z" equ "%HtmlFile%.html" (
                cls
                echo Fake Page Detected!!
                del "%HtmlFile%.html"
                echo "%HtmlFile%.html" was deleted.
                pause >nul
            )
        )
    )
)
pause >nul
```

This batch file first defines an environment variable `HtmlFile` with just a double quote as string value.

The next line after the user prompt removes all double quotes enter perhaps by the user from string. This results in an empty string if the user on prompt just hit RETURN or ENTER without entering any file name. In this case the batch file exits.

Next the batch code checks if name of HTML file was entered with ".html" at end. As the file extension is automatically added by batch code (for some unknown reason), the string ".html" is removed from name of file.

It could happen once again that the remaining string is now an empty string.

Last the batch file checks if the file name with absolute or relative path can be found at all in file system. Otherwise and error message is output.

Please note that this batch file as is cannot evaluate web pages using HTTP (hyper text transfer protocol) or other protocols for accessing files in WWW. It can be used only for files on local drives, network drives or public shares via UNC path.

All references to environment variable `HtmlFile` are enclosed in double quotes as required in case of a space or other special characters are present in the file name (with or without path) entered by batch file user.